# centos system can't compile lkm

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

I installed the Linux headers and i create Makefile and try to build it but I got error that I cant find on the internet 
this is the error

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64/build M=/home/daniel modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64'
arch/x86/Makefile:184: *** Compiler lacks asm-goto support..  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 2
```

and  this is my Makefile

```
 obj-m :=   hook.o
 export-objs := hook.o

 all:
         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Did you install a compiler?  What compiler?  If you run `gcc --version` what does it say?

Comment: I have the newest version i install it with yum

Comment: Well, cutting and pasting that error into Google gives many hits, such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456767/make-menuconfig-error-while-trying-to-build-kernel ...

Comment: @MadScientist well guys i figure it out I reinstall the kernel source and follow the developing tool and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try running this:

```
yum group install "Development Tools"
```